# "Write operation failed: computed property "posts" is readonly"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I try remove post from PostList, but getting an error

```
<PostList
    :posts="sortedAndSearchedPosts"
    @remove="removePost"
    v-if="!isPostsLoading"
  />
```

remove post function

```
 removePost(post) {
      this.posts = this.posts.filter((p) => p.id !== post.id);
    },
```

posts initialized here

```
 computed: {
    ...mapState({
      posts: (state) => state.post.posts,
    }),
    ...mapGetters({
      sortedPosts: "post/sortedPosts",
      sortedAndSearchedPosts: "post/sortedAndSearchedPosts",
    }),
  },
```

Comment: Could you add how `this.posts` is initialised please?

Comment: @Baobab posts initialized in mapState

Comment: I see, any thoughts on the solution below then? Replacing ‘posts’ with ‘localPosts’ perhaps then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear where `this.posts` are actually initially set up.
If I guess your architecture right, I see 2 options for you:

- either directly remove the post in your store so that `sortedAndSearchedPosts` reflects the change directly
- if you don't want to update the global state, build a local copy when you initialise `posts`:

```js
data () {
   return {
      posts: [...this.sortedAndSearchedPosts],
      ...
   }
},
```

and update your code to use the local list of posts:

```js
<PostList
    :posts="posts"
    ...
  />
```

Hope this helps!